# Filesystem errors after resuming from hibernate/suspend

Tags: release-loki, suspend, filesystem

I have been using elementary OS on my laptop for nearly a month now and have had a lot of trouble with both hibernation and suspend (resuming to a black screen or frozen desktop). Hibernation is the most troublesome, to the point where I've given up on getting it to work. The biggest issue however is this:

```
[24966.962483] EXT4-fs error (device sda7): ext4_iget:4389: inode #1051637: comm updatedb.mlocat: bogus i_mode (0)
[24966.992891] Aborting journal on device sda7-8.
[24967.012781] EXT4-fs (sda7): Remounting filesystem read-only
[24967.012820] EXT4-fs error (device sda7): ext4_iget:4389: inode #1051638: comm updatedb.mlocat: bogus i_mode (0)
[24967.037617] EXT4-fs error (device sda7): ext4_iget:4389: inode #1051639: comm updatedb.mlocat: bogus i_mode (0)
[24967.048450] EXT4-fs error (device sda7): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
```

This has happened a total of five times now either when coming out of hibernate or waking from sleep. Each time after restarting I either get a message telling me to run `fsck` manually or, most commonly, just `grub>`. In either case, booting from a live USB and running `fsck -y /dev/sda7` fixes things for a bit but it's not a cure. I even reinstalled two weeks ago for an unrelated reason but it happened again yesterday after waking my laptop from sleep. What I want to know is why this keeps happening and how to fix it for good.

Edit: Also I dual boot with Windows 10

Edit 2: It's been a while (months) and the original issue hasn't quite been resolved, but things aren't as bad as before which makes me think either something was fixed in an update or I just have some dodgy hardware. Regarding the error that I first posted, I haven't seen that one since then and haven't been forced to run `fsck` either. Still, I don't hibernate anymore.

Sleep doesn't trigger freezes as often as before but still causes some problems. A few weeks ago, I got this... ominous looking error: [image: an ugly hard drive error]

I checked the [SMART data](https://pastebin.com/kyf2mkti) and while I'm not too sure what to make of it, I think the section labeled *ATA error count* should be zero.

Edit 3: So the computer in question had an unfortunate encounter with some hot coffee a few months ago and has been replaced. My new laptop has an SSD partitioned between Windows 10 and Elementary and it handles sleep *perfectly*. I can't say anything about hibernation since I don't have a swap partition but honestly, I've gotten use to using sleep only so it's not a big deal anymore.

I'm willing to close this as a hardware issue with my older laptop since I don't trust any computer that throws IO errors and would have replaced the hard drive at some point. Thanks to everyone who replied!

Comment: I have the same problem I believe. I am running Loki on a Toshiba Satelite L755-s5112.

When logging in after suspend or sleep it will freeze and or go to black screen. No matter how long I wait it doesn't come out of it.

Comment: This is something that also happens on Windows. It has something to do with hardware. Make it so that your computer never sleeps or hibernates. Set the shutdown button to do nothing. (Something the Elementary guys REALLY need to fix.) Use the GUI/Terminal to shutdown your computer from now on and don't hibernate it.

Comment: This might be related to your swap partition. Are you running a swap partition and is it an appropriate size (at least as large as your ram)?

Comment: @pretzeljones I have 8GB of ram and a 9GB swap partition.

Comment: @eosdude I gave up on hibernation in elementary. As for windows, I only had one hibernation induced bsod on this computer back when it was running Windows 8.1 but never in Win10. I usually shutdown from the GUI anyway but I'll also keep it from sleeping when idle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no longer using this laptop, however I feel comfortable saying that this was a hardware problem and not really an issue with elementary. Sleep got more reliable with updates but hibernation issues persisted and most of the errors were related to my hard drive. Once I started getting some unusual lag under *both* operating systems, I planned on replacing the hard drive. But then I knocked my coffee over and it spilled all over my laptop and notes. I just replaced the whole thing.

A new computer seems to have solved this issue, although that might be extreme for most. This computer was set up in a similar way; SSD partitions between Windows 10 and elementary and for the last 3 months it's been great! Sleep works fine, and not a single filesystem error, boot failure... it just works.

If anyone else encounters this issue, check your hardware and back up your files! Don't pour coffee on your computer but be prepared in case anything fails!